# Different outputs while applying a filter to an audio signal

Tags: c, audio, signals, wav

Goodevening, I am writing a simple software in C that reads a wav audio file using libsndfile library (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html), than the samples go to a process function where I apply a filter to the signal (second order Butterworth low pass filter, applyed with the transposed direct form II). After that I write the result to a new wav file.
If, instead of the filter, I apply simple operations (like to muliply samples for a constant) it works fine, but when I apply the filter it creates a lot of noise.
I tried to print the values of the samples after the filter and before they are written in the new file and I got the same values as I got from Matlab (where the output I get is perfect), but they are different from the values I got if I read the output written by the library.

```
static void processAudio (double *buffer, int length)
{   
    //arrays a and b are the coefficients
    double a[] = {   1,
                    -1.799096409484668,
                     0.817512403384758};


    double b[] = {  0.004603998475022,
                    0.009207996950045,
                    0.004603998475022};

    //arrays a_ and b_ are the coefficients normalized 
    double a_[] = {1,a[1]/b[0],a[2]/b[0]};
    double b_[] = {1,b[1]/b[0],b[2]/b[0]};
    double gain = b[0]/a[0];

    double reg[] ={0,0}; //memory registers

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {   
        if(i%2==0) //just left channel is changed
        {  
            //TRANSPOSED DIRECT FORM II
            double input = *(buffer+i);
            double output =(input + reg[0])*gain;

            reg[0] = reg[1]+b_[1]*input-a_[1]*output;
            reg[1] = b_[2]*input - a_[2]*output;

            *(buffer+i) = output;

        }
    }   
} 



//that function is called in the main method inside this cycle
int main(void)
{
    ...

    while ((framesRead = sf_read_double(inputFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH)))
    {   

            processAudio(buffer, framesRead);

            sf_write_double(outputFile, buffer, framesRead);
    }

    ...
}
```

If I print the results just after the filter I get:

```
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
-0.00000014050288
-0.00000025277823
0.00000050310774
0.00000209530885
0.00000420138311
0.00000725078112
0.00001115570320
0.00001554761090
0.00002053775981
0.00002550357112
0.00002796948679
0.00000727086200
-0.00006401853354
...
```

If I read the output file the results are

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3.05175781250000e-05
3.05175781250000e-05
3.05175781250000e-05
3.05175781250000e-05
0
-6.10351562500000e-05
-0.000366210937500000
-0.00183105468750000
-0.00601196289062500
-0.0140075683593750
-0.0261840820312500
-0.0421142578125000
-0.0610656738281250
-0.0820617675781250
-0.104156494140625
-0.126342773437500
-0.147766113281250
-0.167663574218750
-0.185363769531250
-0.200378417968750
-0.212280273437500
...
```

They are very different. I don't really know what's going on. If you have an idea let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be an actual [mcve]. What types are `a` and `b`?

Comment: I added the coefficients I am using...

Comment: Seems like this whole question is one big red herring. The question focuses on the filter, and yet you're apparently happy with the output of the filter. It's only writing/reading the file that seems to be the problem. In other words, the problem has something to do with `sf_write_double`. So I'd get rid of the other junk, and just experiment with `sf_write_double` to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting different outputs because you're not keeping the states of the filter. In every iteration of the frame loop, you're resetting the filter state to initial state `{0.0, 0.0}`. Also, don't normalize the coefficients, since MATLAB does this for you. Just take the coefficients from MATLAB and apply it to the filter.

I would form a struct to keep the state of the filter, like this:

```
struct biquad {
    double b0, b1, b2, a1, a2; // Note: MATLAB will always normalize a0 to 1.0, so no need to process that.
    double r0, r1;
};
```

Then, I would add a function like `biquad_process`, something like this:

```
void process_biquad(struct biquad *self, double *buffer, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double x = buffer[i];
        double y = (x * self->b0) + self->r0;

        self->r0 = self->r1 + (x * self->b1) - (self->a1 * y);
        self->r1 = (self->b2 * x) - (self->a2 * y);

        buffer[i] = y;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `main()` function, you can load the audio in buffer and process each chunk like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct biquad *bq = calloc(1, sizeof(struct biquad));

    // Take coefficients from MATLAB and put them here
    bq->b0 = ...
    bq->b1 = ...

    // Set initial state to 0.0
    bq->r0 = bq->r1 = 0.0;
    ...

    while ((framesRead = sf_read_double(inputFile, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH)))
    {   

            process_biquad(bq, buffer, framesRead);

            sf_write_double(outputFile, buffer, framesRead);
    }

    ...
}
```

Hopefully this helps.